# Unable to remove optional Word from string?

Tags: ios, swift

**Unable to remove optional word**

**Code :**

```
let questionidstr : String! = fetchResults.valueForKey("questionID").objectAtIndex(Counter) as? String
```

output : 
 Optional(16)

Required output :
 16

Comment: What type is `fetchResults`? Are you talking about Core Data? Please provide more information. Basically you have to unwrap the optional eventually. And why do you assign an optional (`String?`) to a implicit unwrapped optional (`String!`)? Most of the explicit type annotations do more harm than good.

Comment: print(quesmtionidstr!)

Answer (score 0):

You are casting it to an optional string with `as? String` and are hence getting optional out. Try the following:

```
if let questionidstr = fetchResults.valueForKey("questionID").objectAtIndex(Counter) as? String {
    // Here, questionidstr will have a non optional value, but if it is nil the runtime will never get here.
}
```

You can force unwrap the string without conditional binding as follows, but please be aware this is unsafe and I discourage it over the above approach:

```
let questionidstr = fetchResults.valueForKey("questionID").objectAtIndex(Counter) as! String
```

Comment: I tried but i want to assign to global string. while assigning global string it showing optional word

Comment: As per your Code :  if let questionIDValue = fetchResults.valueForKey("questionID").objectAtIndex(Counter) as? String {
                
                let dict = ["Answer": firstStr , "QuestionID" : questionIDValue ]
                paramArr.addObject(dict)
            }

Comment: That dictionary is pointless, it will be deallocated from memory straight away. You need to make it a property on your instance instead.